# Accessing other people's timelines with Twitter API

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

Ok so I have been experimenting with the Fabric SDK and the Twitter API calls.  I know how to get the timeline of the user currently logged in (tweets of everyone they follow) with *https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json*, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the timeline of another user based on their Twitter ID.  Essentially using the above API call to get the user_timeline of another person.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Twitter does not permit you to view the contents of another user's timeline. (The `statuses/user_timeline` REST endpoint will only return tweets recently posted or retweeted by them, not the aggregated contents of timelines they're following.)

Generally speaking, if you can't do it from the twitter.com web interface, you can't do it through the API either. This is no exception.